# How to rectify code from zero division error:

Tags: python, data-structures, divide-by-zero

I am writing a program to find the cube root of a number. I am getting a division by zero error. I have changed all values to float but still getting the error.

Here is the code.

```
def cube_root(num):
    import random
    g = random.randint(1,num+1)
    new_g = float(num/(g*g))
    check_ifclose(g,new_g,num)

def check_ifclose(g,new_g,num):
    from math import isclose
    if isclose(g, new_g, abs_tol=0.0000001):
        print("The cube root of ",num,"is ",float(new_g))
    else:
        g = float(new_g)
        new_g = float(num/(g*g))
        check_ifclose(g,new_g,num)
```

This is the error that I am getting

```
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-7ad3ad630bd7> in <module>
----> 1 cube_root(16)

<ipython-input-52-46121e93a109> in cube_root(num)
      3     g = random.randint(1,num+1)
      4     new_g = float(num/(g*g))
----> 5     check_ifclose(g,new_g,num)
      6 
      7 def check_ifclose(g,new_g,num):

<ipython-input-52-46121e93a109> in check_ifclose(g, new_g, num)
     12         g = float(new_g)
     13         new_g = float(num/(g*g))
---> 14         check_ifclose(g,new_g,num)

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Comment: Please add the error trace here.

Comment: Why don't you print the values during each iteration? You'll see what happens, you can then try to debug it and re-think your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you print the values during each iteration? You'll see what happens, you can then try to debug it and re-think your solution

Just do:

```
def cube_root(num):
    import random
    g = random.randint(1,num+1)
    new_g = float(num/(g*g))
    print("g", g, "new_g", new_g, "num", num)
    check_ifclose(g,new_g,num)

def check_ifclose(g,new_g,num):
    from math import isclose
    print("g", g, "new_g", new_g, "num", num)
    if isclose(g, new_g, abs_tol=0.0000001):
        print("The cube root of ",num,"is ",float(new_g))
    else:
        g = float(new_g)
        new_g = float(num/(g*g))
        check_ifclose(g,new_g,num)
```

Then for `cube_root(16)` you'll get the output:

```
>>> cube_root(16)
g 2 new_g 4.0 num 16
g 2 new_g 4.0 num 16
g 4.0 new_g 1.0 num 16
g 1.0 new_g 16.0 num 16
g 16.0 new_g 0.0625 num 16
g 0.0625 new_g 4096.0 num 16
g 4096.0 new_g 9.5367431640625e-07 num 16
g 9.5367431640625e-07 new_g 17592186044416.0 num 16
g 17592186044416.0 new_g 5.169878828456423e-26 num 16
g 5.169878828456423e-26 new_g 5.986310706507379e+51 num 16
g 5.986310706507379e+51 new_g 4.464794497196387e-103 num 16
g 4.464794497196387e-103 new_g 8.02633041618099e+205 num 16
g 8.02633041618099e+205 new_g 0.0 num 16
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in cube_root
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in check_ifclose
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in check_ifclose
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in check_ifclose
  [Previous line repeated 8 more times]
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in check_ifclose
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

As you can see, it's like Razmik said about the small numbers.

But why?

Because your solution is flawed. Are you sure you should calculate `new_g` like that? If you look here, **it goes haywire - very small, then very big, then again small**... Why don't you try e.g. setting new_g as average of old and current new to balance it?

---

### EDIT: Decided to check my last suggestion, it works fine now.

```
def cube_root(num):
    import random
    g = random.randint(1,num+1)
    new_g = float(num/(g*g))
    print("g", g, "new_g", new_g, "num", num)
    check_ifclose(g,new_g,num)

def check_ifclose(g,new_g,num):
    from math import isclose
    print("g", g, "new_g", new_g, "num", num)
    if isclose(g, new_g, abs_tol=0.0000001):
        print("The cube root of ",num,"is ",float(new_g))
    else:
        g = float(new_g)
        new_g = (g+float(num/(g*g)))/2
        check_ifclose(g,new_g,num)
```

```
>>> cube_root(16)
g 3 new_g 1.7777777777777777 num 16
g 3 new_g 1.7777777777777777 num 16
g 1.7777777777777777 new_g 3.420138888888889 num 16
g 3.420138888888889 new_g 2.3939850310351836 num 16
g 2.3939850310351836 new_g 2.592869433541053 num 16
g 2.592869433541053 new_g 2.4863846555355664 num 16
g 2.4863846555355664 new_g 2.537249169224923 num 16
g 2.537249169224923 new_g 2.51131729000868 num 16
g 2.51131729000868 new_g 2.524147960725603 num 16
g 2.524147960725603 new_g 2.517700180896523 num 16
g 2.517700180896523 new_g 2.52091579334918 num 16
g 2.52091579334918 new_g 2.519305938864469 num 16
g 2.519305938864469 new_g 2.520110351423893 num 16
g 2.520110351423893 new_g 2.51970801680198 num 16
g 2.51970801680198 new_g 2.5199091519863974 num 16
g 2.5199091519863974 new_g 2.5198085763676823 num 16
g 2.5198085763676823 new_g 2.519858862169772 num 16
g 2.519858862169772 new_g 2.519833718766991 num 16
g 2.519833718766991 new_g 2.5198462903429375 num 16
g 2.5198462903429375 new_g 2.519840004523604 num 16
g 2.519840004523604 new_g 2.519843147425431 num 16
g 2.519843147425431 new_g 2.519841575972557 num 16
g 2.519841575972557 new_g 2.519842361698504 num 16
g 2.519842361698504 new_g 2.519841968835408 num 16
g 2.519841968835408 new_g 2.5198421652669256 num 16
g 2.5198421652669256 new_g 2.519842067051159 num 16
The cube root of  16 is  2.519842067051159
```

Comment: No problem. Maths says your number sequence should be convergent and its limit should be the root. Let's look how it looks in reality: g1 = n/(g0*g0), g2 = n/(g1*g1) = (g0^4)/n... and so on. If g0>1 (and it was like that), odd g's tend to 0, even g's tend to infinity. | What I suggested wasn't even based on maths (I didn't write it down before now) but on the most used approach in numerical calculations: you want to adjust the current value, not use something completely different. ^_^

Comment: Yes. In my logic, I was just going to tend to zero and infinity.

Comment: I didn't think the logic through. I was somehow dumb enough to think that if i set my first 'g' to more than 1, I am assured of a 'g' value higher than 1 throughout the iteration!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that if you have very small numbers as `g` (less than `1e-200`) then the `g * g` python "treats" as 0. Check here https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/floatingpoint.html.

Comment: But I did g = random.rantint(1,num) so that the value of g is atleast 1. so, how do i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

in `new_g = float(num/(g*g))`, `g*g` is floating number. which have decimals more the 308 which leads the value to 0.0.

for finding cube root you can try `num**1/3`

Comment: I am trying to do the program without using builtin methods for calculating powers

Comment: One way can be used that you take only a few decimals points.